# How to create an initial population of 20 chromosomes with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, loops, binary

I'm trying to generate the initial population for a genetic algorithm. I need to generate 20 random binary strings of length 18. I have been able to generate just one chain. My question is: How do I use another loop in order to generate the 20 strings that I need?

I think that this could solved using nested loops. I've tried to do that but I don't know how to use them correctly.

`import random`

`binaryString = []
for i in range(0, 18):
    x = str(random.randint(0, 1))
    binaryString.append(x)
print (''.join(binaryString))`

Answer (score 0):

`import numpy as geek`

`num_bits = 18`

`individualsPer_pop = 20`

`#Defining the population size`

`pop_size = (individualsPer_pop,num_bits) # The population will have`

`individualsPer-pop` `chromosome where each chromosome has num_bits genes.`

`#Creating the initial population.`

`new_population = geek.random.randint(low = 0, high = 2, size = pop_size)`

`print(new_population)`